# Copy data from one sheet to another with the cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet "Data". With this sheet, I am looking into the column K. If it is red in colour then I am extract the complete row and copy them to another sheet " Delay".

I am following the below code. The code does not have any error but, It just copies 4 rows of red while I have 12 rows.

Could anyone help me to find where I am wrong and what changes I need?

```
Sub delay()
Dim cell As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim a As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Data").Range("K:K"))
For Each cell In Sheets("Data").Range("K5:K" & a)
If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Delayed").Range("K:K"))
Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Delayed").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
End If

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the rationale for using `CountA`?  Is column K guaranteed to be non-empty down to the last used cell in that column?

Comment: @YowE3K no it is not guaranteed

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve with the `CountA`?  `CountA` counts how many non-empty cells exist in column K, and you are then using that to generate `"K5:K" & a` and `"A" & nextrow + 1`, i.e. some sort of range.  Why does the number or non-empty cells determine the last row you will be processing?

Comment: Maybe check out [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169445/6535336).

Comment: @YowE3K so you mean to tell instead of using countA I could use lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row  something like this ?

Comment: No - `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` will (assuming A1 and A2 are not empty) find the last non-empty cell before the **first** empty cell.  If you were using `CountA` to get the number of non-empty cells and it wasn't returning the total number of cells then you obviously have some empty cells in your range.  Therefore you probably want to find the first non-empty cell starting from the bottom of the worksheet.  (See the link in my previous comment for ways of doing that.)

Comment: Thank you YowE3k :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all:**
`WorksheetFunction.CountA` counts the number of cells that are not empty and the values within the list of arguments, you can't use it to count the total number of rows or to find number of the last row (unless all cells are not empty).
What you might need is:

```
nmbRows = Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("SheetName").Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

or something less blunt.
Using CountA can result in constriction of your range of search which will lead in data loss or, in your case, inserting a row in incorrect place.
*Example:*
Result of

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim a As Long
    a = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ëèñò1").Range("A:A"))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ëèñò1").Range("B1").Value = a
End Sub
```

is
[image]
**Second:**
Be cautious, add a reference to each `range`, `sheet` as

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("K5:K" & nmbRows)
```

By doing this you can always be certain you're refering to correct range you want to check.

**Another note:**
I'm not VBA expert but if I were you I would count number of rows for each sheet respectively at the start of the macro, in loop I would use `nextrow=nextrow + 1` construction instead of calling function each time.

Comment: For compatibility with larger sheets, you would be wiser using `nmbRows = Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("SheetName").Range("K" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` instead of row 65,500 up.

Comment: You should qualify your `Rows` to specify which worksheet you are referring to (especially if there are multiple workbooks open which means some may have a `Rows.Count` of 65536 and others may have 1048576).  Therefore use `nmbRows = Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("SheetName").Range("K" & Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("SheetName").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.